# Conditional Angular visible at the same time

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-switch="signedIn()">
  <a ng-switch-when="false" >Text1</a>
  <a ng-href="#/post_form" ng-switch-when="true">Text2</a>
</div>
```

Edit//

When $scope.signedIn is getting changed both Text1 and Text2 are visible. 
So it works as intended untill you log in/log out - then for a second both Text1 and Text2 are visible.

Edit//

All answers suggesting using ng-if ng-hide/show - problem is still there.

I know that ng-if is "DOM friendly".

Comment: Please provide more information, a plnkr would be helpful

Comment: Or at least the code of the controller

Comment: Without a plunker example, I'm not sure if this directly applies, but from the Angular docs: "The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display" - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was caused by also applying transition on border-bottom property, removing it solved problem.

Answer (score 2):

I understand the simplicity and readability of the switch, as well as the nesting that it provides, but I would suggest going with something more basic.

You can certainly use the `ng-show`/`ng-hide` approach that rhasarub suggested in their answer, but because you appear to be doing something regarding login, I would suggest using `ng-if`. The difference is that when the condition is not met, then the DOM is not rendered at all, so it cannot be inspected by a curious/knowledgeable user.

```
<a ng-if="!signedIn()" >Text1</a>
<a ng-href="#/post_form" ng-if="signedIn()">Text2</a>
```

Comment: I know that ng-if is "DOM friendly". But problem is still there. I have updated description.

Comment: Can you please provide the code of your controller, or at least that method. The value should only ever be one or the other and the DOM would get updated once when the digest loop is run. Is there any CSS that could be causing a delay in show/hide via `ngAnimate`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ng-switch for a simple boolean value. You can use ng-show and ng-hide instead:

```
<a ng-hide="signedIn()" >Text1</a>
<a ng-href="#/post_form" ng-show="signedIn()">Text2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-switch-on="signedIn()">
  <a ng-switch-when="false">Text1</a>
  <a ng-href="#/post_form" ng-switch-when="true">Text2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Not changing anything.